# Simple transient simulation model for synchronous generators

Tags: power, power-grid, synchronous-motor

I am writing a simple transient circuit simulator as a personal hobby/experiment. My ultimate goal is to develop a simple 2D game for teaching/learning concepts of power systems in an intuitive way. I have enough code to simulate vsin, R, L and C and probe any node voltage in a scope. I am not sure how I can model a synchronous generator. I tried changing the voltage and frequency of the vsin linearly depending on the instantaneous current it is supplying, but when I put two such devices in parallel, they don’t remain in sync. My question is what is the simplest way to model a synchronous generator such that two differently rated generators will remain in sync when connected in parallel.

Comment: Cool project! So, motors are transducers: they convert between electrical and mechanical power. Do you intend to model the mechanical rotation (and whatever's connected -- inertia, speed, torque)? Or just assume everything is common on a fixed-speed shaft? Or what?

Comment: So currently I just have a “phase angle” for the motor shaft. When the instantaneous power is below the rated amount the phase angle changes at a constant rate, but if the current goes above a threshold (what the shaft can provide) then I slow down the “shaft rotation speed” which is same as the sine wave frequency

Answer (score 1):

If you want your model to represent the power system, then I recommend to take a look at a power systems reference text like *Power System Analysis* by Grainger and Stevenson, particularly the chapter on power system stability. The simplest approach for power systems is a quasi-steady-state model that considers angles as deviations from a synchronous reference. Neglect losses use what is called the "DC power flow" model that is a linear relationship between node angles and power injections. While that approximates transmission lines as inductors, it doesn't let you model losses, unbalances, or shunt L or C components and doesn't represent off-nominal voltage magnitudes.

If you want to consider R, L, and C components and solve it like a circuit that follows the time domain voltages and currents (waveforms not phasors), then in the power systems world this is a "transient model" such as might be built in an EMTP-type program. The generator models are generally much more complex because the machine dynamics that they approximate are complex or else they are dead simple (just a fixed frequency voltage source behind a reactance) because the phenomenon of interest (e.g. lightning or switching surges) are so fast compared to the machine dynamics.

The **simplest** time-domain generator model that comes to my mind would be a voltage source with a frequency that has some inertia and changes based on the mismatch between input mechanical power and output electrical power. To maintain synchronism you would have a feedback loop to change input mechanical power based on deviation from nominal frequency. If the feedback is just proportional control, then this is known as "droop control". Let me try to write it out in equations:

$$
v = V_m \sin(\delta) \\
\delta' = \omega \\
\omega' = \frac{P_m - P_e}{M} \\
P_m = P_{set} - K \frac{\omega - \omega_{set}}{\omega_{set}} \\
P_e = v i
$$

The generator current would be calculated from the above internal voltage model behind an inductance that is connected to the rest of your network.

This neglects any terminal voltage regulation. This is a very simple generator model that I think should be able to maintain synchronism. For more sophisticated models, I recommend a careful look at power systems modeling references.

Comment: That is insightful. Since the objective of my “game” is to show the history of power systems as well (starting from DC), I had to implement the RLC circuit solver anyway. I think my simple generator model was missing that fact that freq has an “intertia”. My model was changing the phase smoothly but omega rapidly. I’ll implement the phase’’ ∝ droop and see if that helps keep synchronism

Comment: Yeah, the inertia comes from the physical rotational inertia of the rotating machine. It's only relatively recently through power electronics devices that generators without inertia have become possible. NREL created an interesting video and paper about this phenomenon: https://www.nrel.gov/news/program/2020/inertia-and-the-power-grid-a-guide-without-the-spin.html

Comment: So this system works really well when I connect a generator to an infinite bus, but how can I limit the power draw from one generator based on total load? I don’t know how the system can reach an equilibrium with all generators sync’ed to same freq so that total load generated equal load demand

Comment: If the power setpoints of the generators sum to the load, then the equilibrium frequency should be the same as the frequency setpoint. If there is a mismatch between the total power setpoint and the total load, then the equilibrium frequency will be different from the frequency setpoint by a linear factor from the feedback gain. (This is a property of proportional feedback control.) If different generators have different feedback gain (a.k.a. "droop") then they will contribute proportionally different amounts to make up the power mismatch.